# Split Multipile delimiter from SQL String

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to Split SQL string with (# and ;)?

Billing Column where string is saved in below format

```
548784545S#15/01/2016;84854555545#13/01/2016;45454554545#21/01/2016
```

Split # and ; I want below format

```
548784545S    15/01/2016
84854555545  13/01/2016
45454554545  21/01/2016
```

So Far what i did

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CNT_SHIPPING_BILLNO, 1,
            CASE CHARINDEX('#', CNT_SHIPPING_BILLNO)
               WHEN 0
                   THEN LEN(CNT_SHIPPING_BILLNO)
               ELSE CHARINDEX('#', CNT_SHIPPING_BILLNO) - 1
           END)
       AS Billno,
       SUBSTRING(CNT_SHIPPING_BILLNO,
           CASE CHARINDEX('#', CNT_SHIPPING_BILLNO)
               WHEN 0
                   THEN LEN(CNT_SHIPPING_BILLNO) + 1
               ELSE CHARINDEX(';', CNT_SHIPPING_BILLNO) + 1
           END, 1000) AS BillDate
FROM SHIPPINGBILL
```

Here I am getting only initial Value using above Query

```
548784545S    15/01/2016;84854555545#13/01/2016;45454554545#21/01/2016
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(MAX) = '548784545S#15/01/2016;84854555545#13/01/2016;45454554545#21/01/2016'

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT x = CONVERT(XML,'<p>' + REPLACE(@t, ';', '</p><p>') + '</p>')
)
SELECT PARSENAME(val, 2), PARSENAME(val, 1)
FROM (
    SELECT val = REPLACE(t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '#', '.')
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('p') t(c)
) t
```

Output -

```
--------------- ------------
548784545S      15/01/2016
84854555545     13/01/2016
45454554545     21/01/2016
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a `Table valued` function to split the string with a delimiter of `;`.

**Function : fn_Split**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(20) = ' ')
RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(   
  position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  value varchar(8000)  
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @index int
SET @index = -1

WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
  BEGIN 
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text) 
    IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
          BREAK 
      END 
    IF (@index > 1) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))  
        SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
      END 
    ELSE
      SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
    END
  RETURN
END
```

Then use this function.

**Query**

```
DECLARE @str AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @str = '548784545S#15/01/2016;84854555545#13/01/2016;45454554545#21/01/2016';

SELECT LEFT(value, CHARINDEX('#', value, 1) - 1) AS Billno,
       RIGHT(value, CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE(value), 1) - 1) AS BillDate
FROM  dbo.fn_Split(@str, ';');
```

**Result**

```
+-------------+------------+
| Billno      | BillDate   |
+-------------+------------+
| 548784545S  | 15/01/2016 |
| 84854555545 | 13/01/2016 |
| 45454554545 | 21/01/2016 |
+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way..

```
declare @str nvarchar(1000)
SET @str = '548784545S#15/01/2016;84854555545#13/01/2016;45454554545#21/01/2016';

SET @str = replace (@str,';',''' as [date]  union all  select  ''' )
SET @str = replace (@str,'#',''' as [Id],  ''' )
SET @str = 'select ''' +@str +''''


exec (@str)
```

**OutPut**

```
548784545S  15/01/2016
84854555545 13/01/2016
45454554545 21/01/2016
```

Answer (score 0):

if one record contain always 3 record you can declare different variable them and store. the record doesn't contain always 3 record 
can you use a script which is like this;

```
DECLARE @XPOS INT
DECLARE @XTMPSTR VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @XBILLSTR VARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @XDATESTR VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @XNUMVERSTR VARCHAR(15)


SELECT @XBILLSTR='548784545S#15/01/2016;84854555545#13/01/2016;45454554545#21/01/2016'

SELECT @XPOS=INSTR(@XBILLSTR,';')

WHILE @XPOS>0 BEGIN
    SELECT @XTMPSTR=SUBSTRING(@XBILLSTR,1,XPOS-1) -- Contain like548784545S#15/01/2016 
    SELECT @XNUMBERSTR=SUBSTRING(@XTMPSTR,1,CHAINDEX('#',XTMPSTR)
    SELECT @XDATESTR=SUBSTRING(@XTMPSTR,CHARINDEX('#,XTMPSTR),LEN(@XTMPSTR))

    SELECT @XBILLSTR=SUBSTRING(@XBILLSTR,XPOS+1,LEN(@XBILLSTR)
    SELECT @XPOS=INSTR(@XBILLSTR,';')
    -- STORE @XNUMBERSTR AND @XBILLSTR
 END
 -- FOR LAST POSITION 
 SELECT @XTMPSTR=@XBILLSTR
 SELECT @XNUMBERSTR=SUBSTRING(@XTMPSTR,1,CHAINDEX('#',XTMPSTR)
 SELECT @XDATESTR=SUBSTRING(@XTMPSTR,CHARINDEX('#,XTMPSTR),LEN(@XTMPSTR))
 -- STORE @XNUMBER AND STORE @XDATESTR
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function (returns a single-column table with fragments, available from SQL Server 2016 and above):

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('#',value)>0 
         THEN SUBSTRING(value,1,CHARINDEX('#',value)-1) 
         ELSE value END column1,  
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('#',value)>0 
         THEN SUBSTRING(value,CHARINDEX('#',value)+1,len(value))  
         ELSE NULL END as column2
FROM STRING_SPLIT('548784545S#15/01/2016;84854555545#13/01/2016;45454554545#21/01/2016', ';')
```

Result:

```
column1      column2
-----------  ----------
548784545S   15/01/2016
84854555545  13/01/2016
45454554545  21/01/2016
```